# Java 8 stream Map<K,V> to List<T>

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

Given that I have some function that takes two parameters  and returns one value , is it possible to convert a Map to a List in a Stream as a non-terminal operation?
The nearest I cam find is to use forEach on the map to create  instances and add them to a pre-defined List, then start a new Stream from that List. Or did I just miss something?

Eg: The classic "find the 3 most frequently occurring words in some long list of words"

```
wordList.stream().collect(groupingBy(Function.identity, Collectors.counting))).
```

(now I want to stream the entrySetof that map)

```
sorted((a,b) -> a.getValue().compareTo(b.getValue))).limit(3).forEach(print...
```

Answer (score 56):

You should get the `entrySet` of the map and glue the entries to the calls of your binary function:

```
inputMap.entrySet().stream().map(e->myFun(e.getKey(),e.getValue()));
```

The result of the above is a stream of `T` instances.

#### Update

Your additional example confirms what was discussed in the comments below: `group by` and `sort` are by their nature terminal operations. They must be performed *in full* to be able to produce even the first element of the output, so involving them as non-terminal operations doesn't buy anything in terms of performance/memory footprint.

It happens that Java 8 defines `sorted` as a non-terminal operation, however that decision could lead to deceptive code because the operation will block until it has received all upstream elements, and will have to retain them all while receiving.

Comment: That just takes a list and streams it. I want to stream the Map, eg
something.stream().collect(...).map((k,v) -> k.toString + v.toString).sorted...etc

Comment: The code in the answer takes a *map* and produces a stream of instances of `T`. There is no trace of a list anywhere.

Comment: You take a stream of the entrySet - yes I get that. But how do you do that if the Map is created in the middle of the stream (ie by a collect) and I want to convert the k,v entries into a stream of a single type and continue processing those in the stream?

Comment: `collect` is a terminal operation, it cannot occur in the middle of a stream. If you want a stream step which produces value pairs, followed by a later step which collapses them into single values, then you'll need a `Pair<K,V>` container class.

Comment: OK. I'll post an example of what I'm trying to do and maybe there's another way. Thanks. J

Comment: If you need to ensure the uniqueness of pairs, then involve a `distinct()` step in the stream.

Comment: Yes, the additional code you have posted confirms what was said above: `group by` and `sorted` are by their nature terminal operations. They must be performed *in full* to be able to produce even the first element of the output. It is not sensible to involve them as non-terminal operations.

Comment: OK, thanks for the insight.  Makes me wonder why sorted isn't terminal though (returns a Stream).

Comment: It's a design choice to make---it may provide some API convenience. On the other hand, many programmers will be bitten by its deceptiveness as that step will block until all upstream items are received, and it will *retain* them all. A similar pitfall hides behind `distinct`.

Comment: For comparison, Clojure does not provide sorting as a lazy sequence.

Answer (score 0):

You can also convert Hashmap entries into ArrayList by using following technique,

```
ArrayList list = hashMap.values();
```