# How to create list of object instead of map with groupingBy collector?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have following stream operation.

```
Map<String, Integer> pieDataMap = expenses.stream()
    .collect(groupingBy(expense -> typeClassifier.apply(expense, chartCriteria), 
                        summingInt(Expense::getCost)));
```

Instead of getting `Map<String, Integer>`, I want to get list of objects of type `PieEntry` class which has two arg constructor `PieEntry(String, Integer)`. In short, I want to convert each entry (of type <String, Integer>) of map to object of `PieEntry` class (with two argument constructor) and collect resultant objects as list.

How can I do that without iterating over the resulting map and creating objects in an extra loop?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java 8 stream Map<K,V> to List<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21233183/java-8-stream-mapk-v-to-listt)

Answer (score 4):

If the question is whether it can be done using the original stream without grouping to a map, then it's not possible. To group the results, the whole input needs to be processed since there is no way to know whether there will be new elements downstream that will end up in one of the groups.

So you have to get a grouping map and then map its entries to `PieEntry` objects:

```
pieDataMap.stream().entrySet().stream().map(entry -> new PieEntry(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
```

You can also chain it to the original stream chain after `.collect()`.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on  " ...the whole input needs to be processed since there is no way to know whether there will be new elements downstream that will end up in one of the groups." ?

Comment: The idea behind streams is that all operations (filter, map, skip, etc.) on the same stream can be processed in one go, without iterating through the input over and over. Stream remains unprocessed until the terminal operation is used, for example `.collect()`, `.min()`, `.max()`, `.count()`, etc. More reading: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps. In your case in order to build groups from the `expenses` input, all items from this input should be traversed. Otherwise there is no way to know final cost for each group.

Answer (score 0):

According to `groupingBy` function signature,

```
static <T,K,A,D> Collector<T,?,Map<K,D>>    groupingBy(Function<? super T,? extends K> classifier, Collector<? super T,A,D> downstream)
```

it returns a collector which produces (collects elements into) a map & as this operation is terminal operation, resulting map can't be processed any more in same statement.